# Why \bigodot appear larger in equation

Tags: symbols

I just found that `\bigodot` appears to be larger in equation than it is in normal math text. A sample latex is:

```
Denote $\bigodot$ as $\subset$ or $\not \subset$. Then a \textbf{set
representation} of $\phi_{1}\barwedge\phi_{2}$ is
$$
\widetilde{\mathcal{S}}(\phi_{1}\barwedge\phi_{2})\,\simeq\,\left(A_{1}\times A_{2},\left.\left(\mathcal{G}_{1}\times \mathcal{G}_{2}\right)\right\vert_{r}, \bigodot\right)
$$
```

I wonder what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: That's a common feature of all symbols whose name starts with `\big`: `\bigotimes`, `\bigcup`, `\bigcup` and so on.

Comment: Do you plan to use it as a relation symbol?

Comment: It's not a solution, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to use the symbol as a relation symbol, define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\subnotsub}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathchoice{\textstyle\bigodot}{\bigodot}{\bigodot}{\bigodot}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Denote $\subnotsub$ as $\subset$ or $\not \subset$. Then a
\emph{set representation} of $\phi_{1}\barwedge\phi_{2}$ is
\[
\widetilde{\mathcal{S}}(\phi_{1}\barwedge\phi_{2})\simeq
\bigl(A_{1}\times A_{2},(\mathcal{G}_{1}\times \mathcal{G}_{2})\vert_{r}, \subnotsub\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to note.

1. `$$` should never used in LaTeX (unless you know precisely why you're using it)
2. I removed all wrong `\left` and `\right` that produce oversized fences and unwanted spacing.
3. I can't stand boldface for emphasis, sorry.
4. Just `{\textstyle\bigodot}` won't work, because it will treat the symbol as an ordinary one.

Comment: I do not understand why you use 3 {\bigodot}. Also what is the use of %? I found that {\textstyle\bigodot} works fine in my pdftex.

Comment: @hermes `\mathchoice` wants four arguments and you want to use `\textstyle` only when the symbol is found in display style. The `%` characters are not really mandatory here, because the definition is about something always found in math mode, but they’re a good habit to avoid spurious and unwanted spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Just replacing `\bigodot` with `{\textstyle\bigodot}` will  do.